# How can i check the model object is 30 days old or not in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-cron

**Info**: I am trying to make monthly billing app. Where a customer can buy a property on a monthly basis payment. i want to change the `pending` attribute True to False if the customer last payment 30 days old.

It is a schedule based app but i am not using **django-crontab** or **celrey**. i can use view funtion for it if user visit the `pending_customers` page the view can check the all and which customers the last payments date `created_at` if the `created_at` datetime is 30 days old. Then the **view** funtion can change the `pending` to False.

`pending_customers` **view** is working fine but it is changed the `pending` to False when i visit the page `pending_customers`. It could not wait for 30 days. if the customer last payment is not 30 days old then how can i hold the **view** funtion until for 30 days?

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """Customer Model"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prop_select = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pending = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Payment(models.Model):
    """Payment Model"""

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='payment')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Payment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.customer.pending = True
        self.customer.save()
```

views.py

```
def pending_customers(request):

    queryset = Customer.objects.all()

    for i in queryset:
        for d in i.payment.filter(created_at__gte=datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=30)).order_by('-pk')[:1]:
            d.customer.pending = False
            d.customer.save()

    context = {
        'customers': queryset,
    }
    return render(request, 'customer/pending-customers.html', context)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're using the wrong condition to mark the `pending_customer` to `False`.
Right now you're doing the opposite (marking those less than or equal to 30)

From what I gather you want to do `created_at__gte=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30))`

That is "get me all the payments that are 30 days or older"

Comment: my question is updated now i also try with `created_at__gte=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30))` but it's not working...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working" a bit more? What's going on, what are you expecting and what's the actual response?

Comment: Dear i want to check the last payment of customer if the customer last payment is 30 day old then the `pending` False else True... but my code and your code working same. It's not checking the last payment object date it's just update the `pending` false

Comment: See the `save` function of Payment class, there's no `pending_customer` field. The `pending` field is probably being set `False` by default.

Comment: yes the `pending` is automatically True when new payment object is created. if this payment is 30 days old then customer goes in `pending` False this is the logic i want to do...

Comment: This is the third time you're editing the code. Please take a better look at what you've written before posting on Stack Overflow. You're logic is correct, just the code is riddled with wrong variable names and invalid expressions.

Comment: i am updating my code to show you your code is not working...